# automatically select an option in a select field based on URL parameter?

Tags: php, jquery, url, parameter-passing, contacts

http://domainname.com/page/?selectfieldOption=enable

when i use a URL like above(for example), it automatically select the option in the select field(), please see the screenshots attached

[URL like this(example)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqIqG.png)

[the URL have the value(parameter) of selected field.then it automatically select to that value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVF6X.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you want to achieve. Some Code would be helpfull. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491336/get-url-parameter-jquery-or-how-to-get-query-string-values-in-js?answertab=votes#tab-top) you can find a jQuery function to access URL parameters.

Comment: First of all Thank you for your response. "i just want to select an option in a select field by Jquery parameter passing. when i search a url like above mentioned(for example). it automatically select the same value in select field in that page "

Comment: In that case the linked solution is what you need.